# Solve optimization bound to a compound sum

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I'm working on a a optimization problem, similar to [The Stigler diet](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop) 
instead of the large list of properties on the example, I have only to properties: carbohydrates  and protein.

The food is available in N cans, each one with different properties and price.  The objective is to obtain the cheaper combination to obtain C kg  of food with a protein value >= a and carbohydrates >= b. For this I´m allowed to take eather fractions of the content or the whole can.

```
food = ["f1","f2","f3","f4"]
kg_available = [10,2,5,8]
protein =       [17,12,16,8]
carbohydrates = [10,14,13,16]
price_per_kg =  [15,11,17,12]



df = pd.DataFrame({"food":food,"kg_available":kg_available,"protein":protein,"carbohydrates":carbohydrates,"price_per_kg":price_per_kg})
```

[image]

This is a sample of the requirements:

```
##            protein,carbohydrates,kg
requirement = [15.5,12.3,11]
```

E.G. I want 2kg of food that have 15.5 of protein and 12.3 of carbohydrates.

Following the example on google site, I have this code:

```
data = [
['f1', 10, 15, 17, 10],
['f2', 2, 11, 12, 14],
['f3', 5, 17, 16, 13],
['f4', 8, 12, 8, 16]
]

nutrients = [
    ["protein",15.5],
    ["carbohydrates",12.3]]


food = [[]] * len(data)

# Objective: minimize the sum of (price-normalized) foods.
objective = solver.Objective()
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    food[i] = solver.NumVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), data[i][0])
    objective.SetCoefficient(food[i], 4)
objective.SetMinimization()

# Create the constraints, one per nutrient.

constraints = [0] * len(nutrients)
for i in range(0, len(nutrients)):
    constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(nutrients[i][1], solver.infinity())
    for j in range(0, len(data)):
        constraints[i].SetCoefficient(food[j], data[j][i+3])


status = solver.Solve()

if status == solver.OPTIMAL:
    # Display the amounts (in dollars) to purchase of each food.
    price = 0
    num_nutrients = len(data[i]) - 3
    nutrients = [0] * (len(data[i]) - 3)
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        price += food[i].solution_value()

        for nutrient in range(0, num_nutrients):
            nutrients[nutrient] += data[i][nutrient+3] * food[i].solution_value()

        if food[i].solution_value() > 0:
            print ("%s = %f" % (data[i][0], food[i].solution_value()))

    print ('Optimal  price: $%.2f' % (price))
else:  # No optimal solution was found.
    if status == solver.FEASIBLE:
        print ('A potentially suboptimal solution was found.')
    else:
        print ('The solver could not solve the problem.')
```

Which almost works, it is returning the following result:

```
f1 = 0.077049
f3 = 0.886885
Optimal  price: $0.96
```

That would be correct, except for the part that is not considering that I need 2kg as well and that I have limited stock for each can.

How can I add that constrain to the problem?